# Why does this code gives wrong answer for test case 5?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector

I was working on problem [1429-C](https://codeforces.com/contest/1492/problem/C), When I devised following approach to solve said question.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    // Variables
    std::string s {};
    std::string t {};
    std::vector<int> v1{};
    std::vector<int> v2{};
    std::vector<int> v3{};
    int m,n {};

    
    // User input

    std::cin >> n >> m >> s >> t; 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); ++i)
    {
        v1.push_back(s.find_first_of(t.at(i)));
        v2.push_back(s.find_last_of(t.at(i)));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.size() - 1; ++i)
    {
        v3.push_back(std::abs(v1.at(i)-v2.at(i+1)));
    }
    
    std::cout << *(std::max_element(v3.begin(), v3.end())) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code seems to work for my every test set except test set 5:
[Detailed analysis](https://codeforces.com/contest/1492/submission/108874861)

Can someone please shed some insight on this question?

Comment: If `t.size()` is `1`, then the second loop has no effect, and dereferencing the result of `std::max_element()` (in your output statement) gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: But problemset specifies that `2 < m < n < 2*10^5`, I tried to dereference `std::element_max()` as a variable. Still it didnot help. :(

Comment: When asking for help, provide the smallest, simplest example you can come up with that compiles, runs, and shows the problem. In this case, instead of reading input from the console and providing a link that, presumably, describes the problematic input, just put the values directly in the program.